# Quaternion camera in 3D space with Pitch and Yaw

Tags: camera, quaternion, glm

I am having trouble implementing a quaternion camera that can fly freely in 3D space with only Pitch and Yaw rotations.

It works fine except when you look up or down and then try to look left or right (Yaw).
Then the camera gets a roll effect which is incorrect.

Here is how I handle Pitch and Yaw:

```
void Camera::rotate(const int& inPitch, const int& inYaw){  

//Look Up and Down
if (inPitch != 0)
{
    quat qPitch = angleAxis((float)inPitch * 0.003f, vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    mQuaternion = qPitch * mQuaternion;
}

//Look Left and Right
if (inYaw != 0)
{
    quat qYaw = angleAxis((float)inYaw * 0.003f, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    mQuaternion = mQuaternion * qYaw;
}

mQuaternion = normalize(mQuaternion);
mat4 reversedView = inverse(mat4_cast(mQuaternion));
mLeft = normalize(vec3(reversedView * vec4(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));
mUp = normalize(vec3(reversedView * vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));
mDirection = normalize(vec3(reversedView * vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));
}
```

And this is how I update my ViewMatrix:

```
void Camera::onUpdate(){
if (mIsMoving[move::MOVING] == true)
{
    ///Position is handeled with flags in each direction
    ///to enable moving in muliple directions at once

    if (mIsMoving[move::FORWAD])
        mPos += mDirection*mVelocity;

    if (mIsMoving[move::BACK])
        mPos -= mDirection*mVelocity;

    if (mIsMoving[move::LEFT])
        mPos += mLeft*mVelocity;

    if (mIsMoving[move::RIGHT])
        mPos -= mLeft*mVelocity;

    if (mIsMoving[move::UP])
        mPos += mUp*mVelocity;

    if (mIsMoving[move::DOWN])
        mPos -= mUp*mVelocity;

    ///Rotation
    mViewMatrix = mat4_cast(mQuaternion);
    ///Translation
    mViewMatrix = glm::translate(mViewMatrix, -mPos);
}
}
```

Comment: This is called Gimbal Lock, and it's occurring because, even though your output is a Quaternion, your stored representation of its rotation is in Euler Angles (pitch & yaw). These are not an appropriate choice for a camera that is allowed to look straight up or down. I'd recommend searching other gimbal lock questions, as this comes up a lot and probably has existing answers that will work for you. The key idea is working with a Quaternion at all times, not just converting to it for your output. Pitch & yaw are handled only incrementally, not stored as your state descriptor.